# Where should I open and close Hibernate session in Struts2 web app when using Hibernate Interceptors

Tags: java, hibernate, session, struts2, interceptor

I am using Hibernate Interceptor session object for each and every CRUD operation's in my Struts2 application, for that I opened session with Hibernate Interceptor implemented object.

I want to use only one Hibernate session per one request in my entire Struts2 application.

For this I opened Hibernate session in Struts Interceptor `intercept()` method and I closed Hibernate session in before finish Struts Interceptor `intercept()`.

But in my application I used 'chain action' calls . at that time I am getting `Session close Exception`, if I try to use Hibernate session in next chain action.

Please, help me where I open and close Hibernate Interceptor session in Struts2 application.

**Interceptor**

```
public class MyStrutsInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  public void init() {
    // I created sessionfactroy object as a static variable 
  }

  public void destroy() {
    // I released the DB resources 
  }
  public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory().openSession(new MyHibernateInterceptor());
    invocation.invoke();
    session.close();
  }
}
```

Hibernate Interceptors implemented class

```
public class MyHibernateInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor{  
    //Override methods
}
```

When I use chain action call `invocation.invoke();` and `session.close();` statement is called 2 times.

Comment: There is no `i`, only `I`; please remember it for the next questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a session to `ThreadLocal`

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

private static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
  Session session = threadLocal.get();

  if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    threadLocal.set(session);
  }

  return session;
}

private static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
  Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
  threadLocal.set(null);

  if (session != null) {
    session.close();
  }
}

public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
  Session session = getSession();
  String result;
  try {
    result = invocation.invoke();
  } finally {
    closeSession();
  }
  return result;
}
```